# Are the rules for variable names in PHP changed?

Tags: php, variables, naming-conventions, rules, variable-names

Previously I knew that "A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores".

But, today I read the following line in the **PHP manual** :

> **Note:** For our purposes here, a letter is a-z, A-Z, and the bytes from 127 through 255 (0x7f-0xff).

The below part is new for me and I want to understand it with some suitable example of variable name prepared using the characters in this last part.

> the bytes from 127 through 255 (0x7f-0xff)

Comment: It just means you can use certain unicode characters: https://3v4l.org/AcagE

Comment: Well 127 is Delete, so you might struggle there, but `$é` for example (130) is a perfectly valid variable name

Comment: @Farkie : The PHP Manual also says "PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not offer native Unicode support". Then how can you say that?

Comment: I did say 'certain' for a reason